# Cannot resolve symbol 'PUBLIC_STATIC_STRING_IDENTIFIER'

Tags: android

Althought I have initialized this variable

```
public static PUBLIC_STATIC_STRING_IDENTIFIER = 0;
```

and then I used it here:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
resultIntent.putExtra(PUBLIC_STATIC_STRING_IDENTIFIER, username);
setResult(Profile.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();
```

this message

```
"Cannot resolve symbol 'PUBLIC_STATIC_STRING_IDENTIFIER'"
```

is still shown. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is `PUBLIC_STATIC_STRING_IDENTIFIER` defined in the same Java class as is the code in your second code snippet?

Comment: public static PUBLIC_STATIC_STRING_IDENTIFIER = 0; make this a String like public static String PUBLIC_STATIC_STRING_IDENTIFIER = "your keyName";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you missed the type. It should be

```
public static final String PUBLIC_STATIC_STRING_IDENTIFIER = "PUBLIC_STATIC_STRING_IDENTIFIER";
```

since the first parameter of `putExtra` is a String

Comment: This worked, but now I get the message "Cannot resolve method 'putExtra(java.lang.String, android.widget.EditText)' "

Comment: `username` is an `EditText`. Change it in `resultIntent.putExtra(PUBLIC_STATIC_STRING_IDENTIFIER, username.getText().toString());`

Answer (score 1):

```
public static PUBLIC_STATIC_STRING_IDENTIFIER = 0;
```

you can not use integer as identifier its need an string

```
public static String PUBLIC_STATIC_STRING_IDENTIFIER = "anyKey";
```

Comment: How would you know, if the type is not specified?